How can I block or remove the News app on my Mac?
I find the News app very distracting. I already have most news sites blocked by redirecting them to localhost in /etc/hosts, which works great for websites.
On my iPhone, I can simply delete the News app, but that's not possible on the Mac. Is there any way I can remove this app from my Mac, or just make it inaccessible?
The best I've been able to find is the ability to limit its screen time to 1 minute, but those limits can be easily overridden. I can also use the third-party Focus.app to block the app from opening but I'd love for it to just always be gone, without needing to start a session in Focus.

Sorry if I'm missing something obvious, but why do you need to block the News app at all? I simply never launch it and that's it.

@jaume Because I have a bad habit of checking the news too much. On my phone, I just deleted the app and it helped. I'd like to do the same on my Mac.

The steps to modify a macOS install depend exactly on your hardware and your chosen build version of macOS. If you edit this to specify what details on your setup are we can likely close this as a duplicate of the many questions we have on how to modify an OS. We also have lots of good content on managing addiction and why anything more intrusive than screen time and having a friend manage the password to unlock a one minute daily restriction is generally not an effective technical solution to a behavioral situation.

No, macOS doesn’t allow you to delete apps that deliver with the system.
Double down on screen time, having a counselor or friend set a parental password that you don’t know to prevent you from changing it. Just like you can trivially reinstall the news app on iOS, you can trivially reinstall macOS and get news app back.
Just remove it from the dock. Right click and select. Also make sure it's not in the Notifications list. I am using Catalina though, maybe yours is different.

Thanks. I can still open it via Spotlight - I'd like to remove it completely.

Hey @Bill I’ve put a hold on this since we can’t answer your direct question without more details, but get some professional help on managing addiction. Anything you can do as admin can normally be reversed no matter how much technical friction you try to impose. Why not set up screen time with reports and a pin and set up a weekly session with your guide that’s helping to hold you accountable for your addiction management goals? You can review the logs (or if you deleted them this week) and build support for new habits?

@bmike Yikes, that's an incredibly harsh response! To elaborate, I basically never use the Dock to open apps, I use Spotlight to open apps. Removing the app from the Dock doesn't really change anything. I think it's pretty common these days for people to want to reduce their easy access to social media or news content - not sure this simple question really justifies a "seek professional help" response....

It wasn’t meant to be harsh, so my apologies @Bill. I read your 1 minute limit a day isn’t sufficient to mean you really can’t control whomever needs to be prevented from even 60 seconds of limited news a day. Please edit your post if you wish to have the team review it for more answers. The answer you have is the full correct answer IMO.

News.app is on the System volume and can't be removed/modified/blocked on modern versions of macOS. You can

use Parental Control/Screen Time to limit the daily use (and have somebody else set the passcode),
use apps like Focus or Self Control,
set up a LaunchDaemon which kills the process whenever it gets started,
block https://apple.news in Little Snitch or your router.

All these methods can be circumvented by an admin user, but that's the same as reinstalling the app on the iPhone.
